# Executing wrapped java app in SSIS

Tags: jar, ssis, exe, execute, launch4j

I've made an appliaction in java which is performing some operations on the database. 
Then I wrapped jar using launch4j (making exe) and it's working fine when I double-click it.
But if I put it as a part of SSIS process (in Execute Process Task) it doesn't make anything. SSIS is marking it as Executed just miliseconds after beginning while it should last at least 10 seconds.

I have already been using Execute Process Task for unzipping files with 7-zip and it worked fine.

How should I run java application as a part of SSIS process?

EDIT: Now I think that my app is executing but ssis doesn't wait for it to ends but continues process while java app is executing :(
Any hints will be appreciated

Comment: My java is sorely outdated. If you skip the custom executable for the command line invocation `java.exe MyJar.jar` or the equivalent in your execute process task, do you get the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The problem was when I was making exe file I picked 'GUI application' option instead of 'Console'
Now it's working fine.